# Google chrome showing font much lighter

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

Im currently running a website but fonts are much lighter in the chrome browser but at the same time when i run the same website in another browser say Firefox,the webpage is displayed better as below :

Pic 1 : chrome

[image]

Pic 2 : Firefox

[image]

Why does this happen ?

Do i have to disable / enable some plugins to view better ?

Chrome extensions :

[image]

Plugins :

[image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zw7n4n9m/)

```
body {
  color: #222;
  font: 14px/19px Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .1;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: do you have any plugins enabled who could might do this? is it a css3 item, like opacity, which is only defined for webkit (chrome)?

Comment: i have tried it in other browsers also ,firefox shows fonts correct,chrome and other browsers dont show them..

Comment: Is it a custom font? what kind of fontfile do you use?

Comment: if i open some website like : http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html ,then also fonts are lighter

Comment: Not for me, the fonts are black in chrome. i think there must be a plugin doing this?

Comment: but there are no extensions

Comment: Put chrome://plugins into the address bar, this is for the plugins and not extensions.

Comment: Have you checked the webkit-style through the in-browser development console?

Comment: Can you show us the CSS applicated on the text?

Comment: yes i have added a fiddle link as well

Comment: @utility I'm running Chrome and this looks absolutely fine to me on Chrome. Do note though that `letter-spacing: .1` doesn't work as you haven't specified a unit.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly im confused on what to do! chrome does not give the desired result in my system

Comment: is there any workaround!?

Comment: I had the same thing with `Box-shadow:inset;` Chrome displayed it much lighter that Firefox. I think that's just because each browser interpret css on their own way. The same but with things like this just a little bit different

Comment: @Vinc199789 yes some sites are showing like that..by the way is there any workaround for that?any softwares..plugins..or tutorials ?

Comment: @utility You can try this. Detect the users browser width Javascript or what you want to use and set if they are using chrome the text color to a darker color.  Take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: it would be helpful if you post as answer with code..please